# Array For loop throwing Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code that sets object properties of a class in a for loop, saving each object as an element in an array, BREobjects(). The very next code is below and the first BREobjects(i).BREdays is throwing an

> Object variable not set error.

It's a Public array so it shouldn't need to be redim'ed or anything. Anyone know what's happening?

Code that sets the object properties:

```
'creates a new object for each BRE day/time combination
count = 0
For Each i In BREitems
    BREdaysString = Split(Cells(i.Row, "c").value, ", ")
    For j = LBound(BREdaysString) To UBound(BREdaysString)

        count = count + 1
        ReDim Preserve BREobjects(count)
        Set BREobjects(count) = New BREpptObjects

        BREobjects(count).BREname = Cells(i.Row, "a").value
        BREobjects(count).BREcategory = Cells(i.Row, "b").value
        BREobjects(count).BREstartTime = Cells(i.Row, "d").value
        BREobjects(count).BRElength = Cells(i.Row, "e").value
        BREobjects(count).BREtimeRight = Right(Cells(i.Row, "d").value, 2)

        BREobjects(count).BREdays = BREdaysString(j)

        'Sets the start row number accounting for BREs that start on the half hour
        If BREobjects(count).BREtimeRight = 0 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREstartRow = (Cells(i.Row, "d").value / 100) + 3
            BREobjects(count).BREremainder = 0
        ElseIf BREobjects(count).BREtimeRight <> 0 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREstartRow = ((Cells(i.Row, "d").value - BREobjects(count).BREtimeRight) / 100) + 3
            BREobjects(count).BREremainder = 1
        End If

        'determines the row the BRE ends in
        If BREobjects(count).BRElength - Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength) = 0 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREendRow = BREobjects(count).BREstartRow + BREobjects(count).BRElength - 1
        ElseIf BREobjects(count).BRElength - Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength) > 0 Or BREobjects(count).BREremainder = 1 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREendRow = BREobjects(count).BREstartRow + Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength)
        End If

        If BREobjects(count).BREremainder = 1 And BREobjects(count).BRElength >= 1 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREendRow = BREobjects(count).BREendRow + 1
        End If

        'sets the end time
        If BREobjects(count).BRElength - Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength) = 0 Then
            BREobjects(count).BREendTime = BREobjects(count).BREstartTime + (100 * BREobjects(count).BRElength)
        ElseIf BREobjects(count).BRElength - Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength) > 0 Then
            BREtimeRight = Right(BREobjects(count).BRElength, 2)
            BREobjects(count).BREendTime = BREobjects(count).BREstartTime + (100 * Fix(BREobjects(count).BRElength)) + (BREtimeRight * 60)
        End If

        BREobjects(count).BREID = BREobjects(count).BREname & " " & BREobjects(count).BREdays & " " & _
        BREobjects(count).BREstartTime & " " & BREobjects(count).BREendTime & " " & BREobjects(count).BRElength
    Next j
    Erase BREdaysString
Next i

'This loop throws an Object variable or with block variable not set error.
'Thrown on the array in the line BREdays = BREobjects(i).BREdays.  
Back:
For i = LBound(BREobjects) To UBound(BREobjects)
    Dim BREdays As String

    BREdays = BREobjects(i).BREdays

    If FiveDay = True And BREdays = "Saturday" Or BREdays = "Sunday" Then
        Call DeleteElement(i, BREobjects())                         'Deletes the BREppt Object from the BREobjects array
        ReDim Preserve BREobjects(UBound(BREobjects) - 1)           'Shrinks the array by one, removing the last one
        GoTo Back                                                   'Restarts the loop because the UBound has changed
    End If
    Debug.Print BREobjects(i).BREID
Next i
```

Comment: More code would be helpful - where is the `Set` actually taking place?

Comment: This modification of `BREobjects` within the loop and the use of `GoTo` is a bit of a code smell btw.

Comment: Edited the OP adding code. code smell...lmao. never heard that. i thought it was a horrible hack too. but hey it worked.

Comment: First BREpptObjects is added to array with count = 1 so BREobjects(0) is undefined.

Comment: moving the count = count + 1 to after the Set BREobjects = New BREpptObjects throws an out of bounds error at count = 1 on the .name property.

Comment: Have you considered using a collection rather than an array ? You will get confused if you use count both for the array index and the Redim. A dim array(1) has 2 elements (assuming the default Option Base of zero). Leave your code as is and avoid BREobjects(0) by starting your delete loop from 1. Better still put the If day = "Saturday" etc condition in the first loop and avoid inserting those days so no need for second loop.

Comment: I've never used collections before. I'll have to research it. I imagine it could reduce, or at least force a refactor for the rest of the code too.  I see your point about BREobjects(0). This code was developed and works using 2010 and now I'm on 2013 and apparently more than a few things are different. I do like the idea of excluding the weekend days in the creation of the objects rather than having to change the array afterwards. Thats a lot of good direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to refactor you code using a collection and move some of the property setting to the class module it could reduce the code to something like this.

```vb
Sub ExportToPPTButton_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, iLastRow As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim BREobjects As New Collection
    Dim obj As BREpptObjects2, arDays As Variant
    Dim i As Long, dow As Variant, sKey As String, s As String
    Dim FiveDays As Boolean

    ' dictionary to count multiple day/time
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    FiveDays = True
    For i = 5 To iLastRow
        s = ws.Cells(i, "D")
        s = Replace(s, " ", "") 'remove spaces
        arDays = Split(s, ",")

        For Each dow In arDays
           s = LCase(Left(dow, 3))
           If (FiveDays = True) And (s = "sat" Or s = "sun") Then
              ' skip weekends
           Else
              Set obj = New BREpptObjects2
              obj.BREDays = dow
              obj.initialise ws.Cells(i, 1)

              ' avoid duplicate day/time
              sKey = obj.BREDays & obj.BREstartTime
              obj.BREpic = dict(sKey) + 0
              dict(sKey) = dict(sKey) + 1

              ' add to collection
              BREobjects.Add obj, obj.BREID
           End If
       Next
    Next

    ' set total objects in cell
    For Each obj In BREobjects
        sKey = obj.BREDays & obj.BREstartTime
        obj.BREobjInCell = dict(sKey)
    Next

    MsgBox BREobjects.count & " objects added to collection"
    For Each obj In BREobjects
        obj.dump ' debug.print objects
    Next

End Sub
```

Note : I used Public here for demo but use Private in your code

```vb
' class BREpptObjects2
Public BREname As String, BRElocation As String, BREcategory As String
Public BREstartTime As String, BREendTime As String
Public BRElength As Double
Public BREDays As String, BREID As String, BREStartRow, BREEndRow
Public BREobjInCell As Integer, BREpic As Integer

Sub initialise(rng As Range)

    Dim StartHour As Integer, StartMin As Integer
    Dim DurHour As Integer, DurMin As Integer
    Dim EndHour As Integer, EndMin As Integer
    With rng
        BREname = .Offset(0, 0).Value ' A
        BRElocation = .Offset(0, 1).Value 'B
        BREcategory = .Offset(0, 2).Value 'C
        BREstartTime = .Offset(0, 4).Value 'E
        BRElength = .Offset(0, 5).Value 'F
    End With

    StartHour = Int(BREstartTime / 100)
    StartMin = BREstartTime Mod 100
    DurHour = Fix(BRElength)
    DurMin = (BRElength - DurHour) * 60

    ' set end time
    EndHour = StartHour + DurHour
    EndMin = StartMin + DurMin
    If EndMin > 60 Then
       EndMin = EndMin - 60
       EndHour = EndHour + 1
    End If
    BREendTime = EndHour * 100 + EndMin

    'Sets the start row number accounting for BREs that start on the half hou
    BREStartRow = StartHour + 3
    BREEndRow = EndHour + 3

    BREID = BREname & " " & BREDays & " " & _
            BREstartTime & " " & BREendTime & " " & BRElength

End Sub

Sub dump()
      Debug.Print "ID [" & BREID & "]"
      Debug.Print "StartTime", BREstartTime, "End TIme", BREendTime, "Length", BRElength
      Debug.Print "StartRow", BREStartRow, "EndRow", BREEndRow
      Debug.Print "pic", BREpic, "objInCell", BREobjInCell
End Sub
```